# Jupyter Notebook - global name not defined with Numba and Dask

Tags: jupyter-notebook, dask, numba

While trying to parallelize a slow function on a large set of images, I faced an error and I was not able to find any information about it. The error appears only when I run the code on a Jupyter Notebook. In a python file, there is another error and I found a fix for this one on this topic about [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/windows.html#multiprocessing-error-without-if-clause-protection).

The snippet code is the following one :

**cell1**

```
import numba
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.multiprocessing import get
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
```

**cell2**

```
def f1(x):
    return x + 1

@numba.jit
def f2(x):
    x1 = f1(x)
    time.sleep(0.05)
    return x1, x

@numba.jit
def f3(x):
    a, b = f2(x)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return a + b

def f4(x, y):
    return f3(x) + y
```

**cell3**

```
nCores = 4 #cpu_count()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100 , size=(100, 2)), columns=["A", "B"])

res = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=nCores).\
   map_partitions(
      lambda df_ : df_.apply(
         lambda x : f4(x.A, x.B), axis=1)).\
   compute(get=get)

print(res)
```

To run this code on a python script if requires before the content of the **cell 3** the famous `if __name__ == "__main__" :`

but this is not working on the Notebook. The error returned is :

> NameError: ("global name 'f2' is not defined", 'occurred at index 50')

Those are some trials I've done :

- If I remove the `@numba.jit`, it works
- If I use the standard pandas apply with `@numba.jit` it works.
- If both are present, it fails

Does someone knows how to fix this in the specific case of a Jupyter Notebook ?

Thanks by advance,

Nicolas

Comment: Recommend you use dask.distributed instead of multiprocessing.